# How to load one image at a time in the Android UI thread

Tags: android, web-services, image, service, background

I currently have a UI that uses an AsyncTask class to make a web service call.  This call gets several pictures and stores them in a HashMap.  The UI is then notified and the UI is created with these images.  However, this sometimes takes as long as 10 - 15 seconds, which is annoying.  Is there a way to populate the UI one picture at a time with a background service so that the user starts to see images faster than they currently are?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a rough example of how to do this:

```
public Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
    int len = urls.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        Bitmap b = downloadImage(urls[i]);
        publishProgress(new Object[] {b, i});
    }
    return null;
}

public void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
    Bitmap b = (Bitmap)values[0];
    Integer bitmapIndex = (Integer)values[1];
    //replace the image at location "bitmapIndex" in your collection of images with "b"
    //update your adapter via notifyDataSetChanged
}
```

Use the `AsyncTask`'s `onProgressUpdate` method to publish progress inside `doInBackground`.  This method(`onProgressUpdate`) runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Right in front of my face.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of this, but just in case, an `AsyncTask` has the `onProgressUpdate` function which you could use to perform operations on the UI thread, before the `AsyncTask` ends with calling `onPostExecute`. From the `doInBackground` method just call `publishProgress` with relevant arguments.